# Como implementar um projeto android separado nas dependências do gradle, sem modificar o caminho ou url

Tags: android, gradle

Tenho este cenário no Gradle (build.gradle)

```
implementation ("br.com.mycompany.feature:feature:$mycompanyFeatureVersion") {
               transitive = true 
               exclude group: 'br.com.mycompany', module: 'comons'
}
```

Preciso apontar o caminho do "Feature" em minhas dependências, estou trabalhando em minha máquina, mas não consigo alterar $mycompanyFeatureVersion. Como posso fazer isso? Não consigo apontar o caminho do .jar diretamente, isso é prática ruim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vá em
Arquivos> Novo> Módulo

É preciso criar um novo módulo (que é uma pasta), deve se inserir o projeto conector(projeto que você quer inserir) nestá pasta-modulo, e inserir no build.gradle do projeto conector os plugins:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

O "library", é para transformar o apk em biblioteca
e o "maven-publish" é para que a pasta possa ser inserida como dependência.

Depois insira na dependencia(build.gradle) com o endereço do modulo
implementation ("us.com.company.project:modulename:$variableifisneeded)

Foi assim que eu resolvi depois de colocar a pergunta no stack